# Computing $\lim_{x\to{0+}}\frac{\tan(x)-x}{x^3}$ without L'Hôpital's rule.

Tags: calculus, limits

> Computing $\lim_{x\to{0+}}\frac{\tan(x)-x}{x^3}$ without L'Hopital

Say $\lim_{x\to{0+}}\frac{\tan(x)-x}{x^3} = L$

For $L$:
$$L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}\\
L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan 2x-2x}{8x^3}\\
4L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac12\tan2x-x}{x^3}\\
3L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac12\tan{2x}-\tan x}{x^3}\\
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}x\frac{\frac1{1-\tan^2x}-1}{x^2}\\
=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\tan x)^3}{x^3}=1\\
\large L=\frac13$$

I found that in another Q, can someone tell me why

$$L=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan 2x-2x}{8x^3}$$

Comment: I'd use the Maclaurin series for sine/cosine.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lhôpital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: Thanks, I just edited my Q on base of that link

Comment: That's a simple change of variable $x\leftrightarrow2x$.

Comment: Can you find series expansion for $\tan x $ in tems of $ x,x^3,x^5.. $ etc? If so the cofficients would be useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x = 2y$ then $y\rightarrow 0$ when $x\rightarrow 0$, so $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} f(x) = \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} f(2y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the McLaurian series of $\tan x$ which is simply $$\tan x=x+\frac {x^3}{3}+ O(x^5)$$

Hence $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac {\tan x-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac {x+x^3/3-x}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac 13=\frac 13$$

Similarly for second one just replace $x$ with $2x$

Comment: This is a good answer to the question, but I want to add that usually restrictions against using L'Hopital's rule come from a point in learning Calculus during which you don't know Taylor/McLaurin series. So, for anyone who hasn't learned to show the first line of this proof, they should not use it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=\arctan y.$ We have $y\to 0^+$ as $x\to 0^+.$

For $x\in (0,\pi /2)$ we have $\frac {\tan x-x}{x^3}=$ $\frac {y-\arctan y}{y^3}\frac {y^3}{x^3}=$ $\frac {(y-\arctan y)}{y^3}(\frac {\tan x}{x})^3.$

We have $\lim_{x\to 0^+}(\frac {\tan x }{x})^3=1.$

Consider $g(y)=y-\arctan y.$

We have $g'(y)-y^2=$ $(1-\frac {1}{1+y^2})-y^2=$ $\frac {-y^4}{1+y^2}\in [-y^4,0].$

Therefore $g(y)=g(y)-g(0)=$ $\int_0^y g'(t)dt=$ $y^3/3-\delta \cdot y^5/5$ for some $\delta \in [0,1].$